# Plotly.extendTraces don't accept hovertext update

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I'm running in circles here. I've built a nice plot, but unfortunately, the hover text isn't working. Please see the last lines in the code; I've commented accordingly. Without the hover text, I get a decent graph, but with it, I don't. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Uncaught Error Error: cannot extend missing or non-array attribute: hovertext
```

I'm not sure what else to explain about the problem.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Temperatur Graph</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="temp" class="subgraphcontent">
        <div class="row" style="padding: 30px;">
            <div id="temp_graph_wrapper" class="border border-2" style="padding: 5px;">
                <div id="temp_plot"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="temp_graph_div" theta0="1220" theta1_vert="1219" theta2_vert="1219" theta3_vert="1220"
        theta4_vert="1219" theta1_hori="1219" theta2_hori="1219" theta3_hori="1221" theta4_hori="1221" counter="1">
    </div>
    <div class="temp_graph_div" theta0="1221" theta1_vert="1220" theta2_vert="1219" theta3_vert="1220"
        theta4_vert="1219" theta1_hori="1218" theta2_hori="1218" theta3_hori="1221" theta4_hori="1220" counter="2">
    </div>
    <div class="temp_graph_div" theta0="1219" theta1_vert="1217" theta2_vert="1217" theta3_vert="1217"
        theta4_vert="1217" theta1_hori="1216" theta2_hori="1216" theta3_hori="1219" theta4_hori="1218" counter="3">
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function setup_temp_graph() {
        var graphdiv = document.getElementById("temp_plot")
        var layout = {
            title: 'Temperatur',
            height: 700,
            width: 930,
            showlegend: false,
            yaxis: {
                ticksuffix: "°C",
                gridwidth: 1,
                color: 'black',
                gridcolor: 'black'
            },
            xaxis: {
                tickmode: "linear",
                tickvals: [0],
                ticktext: [""],
                gridwidth: 1,
                color: 'black',
                gridcolor: 'black'
            },
            shapes: [
            ]
        };
        var trace1 = {
            y: [],
            x: [],
            type: 'scatter',
        };

        var data = [trace1];

        Plotly.newPlot(graphdiv, data, layout, { displayModeBar: false }, { responsive: true });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setup_temp_graph();

        $('.temp_graph_div').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var theta0 = $this.attr("theta0");
            var theta1_vert = $this.attr("theta1_vert");
            var theta2_vert = $this.attr("theta2_vert");
            var theta3_vert = $this.attr("theta3_vert");
            var theta4_vert = $this.attr("theta4_vert");
            var counter = parseInt($this.attr("counter"));
            update_temp_graph(
                theta0, theta1_vert, theta2_vert, theta3_vert, theta4_vert, counter
            );
        });
    });

    function update_temp_graph(theta0, theta1_vert, theta2_vert, theta3_vert, theta4_vert, counter) {
        if (theta0 === "" || theta1_vert === "" || theta2_vert === "" || theta3_vert === "" || theta4_vert === "" || counter === "") {
            return; // Exit the function if any of the variables is empty
        }

        var graphDiv = document.getElementById("temp_plot");

        var xValues = [counter - 0.5, counter - 0.4, counter - 0.3, counter];

        var yValues = [];
        var hoverText = [];

        if (counter == 1) {
            xValues.unshift(0); // Add 0 to the beginning of the xValues array
            yValues.push(parseFloat(theta0));
            hoverText.push('Einlauf');
        }

        yValues = yValues.concat([
            parseFloat(theta1_vert.replace(",", ".")),
            parseFloat(theta2_vert.replace(",", ".")),
            parseFloat(theta3_vert.replace(",", ".")),
            parseFloat(theta4_vert.replace(",", "."))
        ]);

        hoverText = hoverText.concat([
            'Strahlung vertical',
            'Abspritzen vertical',
            'Umformung vertical',
            'Leitung vertical',
        ]);

        var traceUpdate = {
            x: xValues,
            y: yValues,
            text: hoverText,
            hoverinfo: 'text',
            hovertext: hoverText,
            mode: 'lines+markers',
            type: 'scatter',
            connectgaps: false
        };
        Plotly.update(graphDiv, traceUpdate, 0);

        //the next line works, but without hovertext
        //   Plotly.extendTraces(graphDiv, { y: [yValues], x: [xValues] }, [0]);
        //the next line crashes the graph
        //  Plotly.extendTraces(graphDiv, { hovertext: [hoverText] }, [0]);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

PS: By the way, I have already extensively tortured ChatGPT on this topic. It doesn't help. And with my fairly extensive programming knowledge, I'm also at a dead end. Well, JavaScript is not really my language.

Comment: Which line is throwing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try and define, in your initial trace setup, `hovertext` as an empty array?
[`Plotly.extendTraces`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyextendtraces) can only add to existing arrays (not create new ones).
If the attribute you are trying to extend is not already defined as an array in your trace `data`, that would explain the error you are seeing (`Uncaught Error Error: cannot extend missing or non-array attribute: hovertext`).

```js
var trace1 = {
    y: [],
    x: [],
    hovertext: [],  // <-- 
    type: 'scatter',
};
```

Then, this should work:

```js
Plotly.extendTraces(graphDiv, { hovertext: [hoverText] }, [0]);
```